# Bootstrap Datepicker Not Working

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am trying to get bootstrap datepicker to work but it does not even show up.
http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/

```
<link href="~/Css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
</script>

<input id="datepicker" value="10/22/2011" />
```

I am using bootstrap 2.1.1

Comment: Put your code within `$(document).ready(function(){ // ... })`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to initialize a datepicker when there's no `#datepicker` element in DOM yet (the corresponding `input` follows `<script>` element, not vice versa).

As `$('#datepicker')` will still return a jQuery-wrapped object (not `null`!), no error will be thrown.

To solve this, either make this call when DOM is loaded:

```
$(function() {
  $('#datepicker').datepicker();
});
```

or move this script into very end of `<body>` element.

I'd choose the first option; moving all the DOM-ready actions into the same `$(function() { ... });` wrapper as well.

Comment: tired loading object on document load but still its not working