# Bootstrap datepicker not responding in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have similar issue like in [Bootstrap Datepicker Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13058725/bootstrap-datepicker-not-working) .I followed the solution of putting datepicker code in document.ready() as

`$(function(){ $('#datepicker').datepicker(); });`

But,still on clicking datepicker icon, it is showing "Stop script running..." pop up.I am using jquery 1.8.3 version with bootstrap version 2.1.1.It is working fine in Jquery version 1.8.1.what change needs to be done for jquery version 1.8.3

Comment: Is it possible that you have an old version of datepicker? [see here](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/issues/144)

Answer (score 4):

This was a bug in the original release in September 2012. Coders have since forked the project and made fixes/improvements - one of them being this IE 7/8 bug...

https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/issues/144

Essentially, download the latest Master build contents and you should be good to go.