# Bootstrap Datepicker vs IE8 - Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8, datepicker

Here is my code:

```
var dpTo = $('#datetimepicker_to').datepicker({
        format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
        startDate: past,
        endDate: today,
        language: '{{ App::getLocale() }}',
        autoclose: true
    })
    .on('changeDate', function(e) {
        if(e.date != null) {
            $('#datetimepicker_from').datepicker("setEndDate", new Date(e.date));
        }
        else {
            $('#datetimepicker_from').datepicker("setEndDate", today);
        }
    });
```

On this line

```
$('#datetimepicker_from').datepicker("setEndDate", new Date(e.date));
```

IE8 displays this error

```
 Object doesn't support this property or method
```

What is happening here ?

Comment: It looks like the `datepicker` plugin is not properly installed or it doesn't work with IE8.  Also, what version of jQuery and jQueryUI are you using?  jQuery versions 1.x support IE8, version 2.x do not.

Comment: Forgot to mention that this is the bootstrap datepicker, not the JQuery UI,sorry.

Comment: So, what version of jQuery and bootstrap are you using?

Comment: JQuery 1.11.1 and Bootstrap 3. It appears that "setEndDate" is the problem here,because if I replace it with "setStartDate" it passes without this error. Any ideas ?

Comment: Here's a reference to a patched version of the bootstrap datepicker that fixes a bug with setEndDate in IE8: https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/blob/master/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js.  I'm wondering if that is your issue?

Comment: More discussion of the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14826783/bootstrap-datepicker-not-responding-in-ie8

Comment: God, you saved my life ! The new version with fixes for IE8 bugs worked perfectly !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this was resolved via things I posted in comments, I will summarize here as an answer to finish off this question.

Here's a reference to a patched version of the bootstrap datepicker that fixes a bug with setEndDate in IE8: https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/blob/master/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js

And, here's some more discussion of the issue: [Bootstrap datepicker not responding in IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14826783/bootstrap-datepicker-not-responding-in-ie8)