# jQuery Date Picker for Bootstrap Not working

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

Jquery date picker is not working on bootstrap, even though the scripts are in the footer can you help me to make it work

I already followed this link "http://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/Simple-Date-Picker-for-Bootstrap.html"

This is the html input field (you can check the live version here https://thehippiekid.co/eight/press **lower part of the website**)

```
<div class="input-append date pull-right" id="dp3" data-date="12-02-2012" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
   <input class="span2" size="16" type="text" value="12-02-2012" />
</div>
```

footer.php

```
<script src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script>
$('.datepicker').datepicker()
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap Datepicker Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13058725/bootstrap-datepicker-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

I just need to put the datepicker class on the input field haha! my bad